# How to get the last not null value from previous rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I know that there are a lot of solutions for this but unfortunately I cannot use partition or keyword TOP. Nothing I tried on earlier posts works.

My table looks like this:
[image]

The result I want is when any completion percentage is NULL it should get the value from last non-value completion percentage, like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is most easily done using `outer apply`:

```
select t.projectname, t.sequence,
       coalesce(t.completion_percentage, t2.completion_percentage) as completion_percentage
from t outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.projectname = t.projectname and
            t2.completion_percentage is null and
            t2.sequence < t.sequence
      order by t2.sequence desc
     ) t2;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
SELECT t2.project_name,t2.sequence,
case when percentage is null then (select percentage from table1  t1 where t1.sequence=t2.sequence-1 )
else t2.percentage end as percentage
FROM table t2
```